# On an editor (gedit, bash command line, vim...) what is the easiest way for a well displayed negative exponent, i.e. : 5.10⁻⁷?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Using the dead char `^` I can type 5.10⁷ easily.
But how doing the same for `-7`?

1. typing `5.10^-7` isn't working,
2. inserting a minus sign before the `⁷` of the previous example isn't appealing: 5.10-⁷
3. knowing the Unicode character `0x207B`, i can insert ⁻ instead, by taking the time to type `\u207B`, and I'll have my wished 5.10⁻⁷. But it's a bit long...

What's the easiest way to enter a negative exponent?

Answer (score 4):

I’m assuming you’re using a French layout — on my system, <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> (using the main keyboard keys, not the numeric keypad) does the right thing: “5.10⁻⁷”. This uses \u207B, [superscript minus](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2070.html). (It doesn’t look great however because ⁻ is too high, at least with the font my browser uses.)

Comment: Yes... it could be one trouble coming in fact from the keyboard layout I'm using...

Comment: To clarify, I’m using a French layout too. Have you tried pressing ^ before - and again before 7?

Comment: this also works as a compose key sequence

Comment: @StephenKitt If I do that it types: `10^-⁷`  and not `10⁻⁷` the minus is the big one and the `^` stays. I understand: I need to use the minus of the `6` num key, not the one of the numpad.

Comment: FWIW on my British keyboard layout on Ubuntu 20.04, ^- with compose gets me *macron* (U+00AF) which is even higher in xterm, not *superscript minus* (U+207B) which looks fine in xterm

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm still not sure why compose __ and compose ^- map to the same character.